# How can i add a view that is under navigation bar and can be used and shown in all viewcontrollers?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using UINavigationController and the root viewcontroller is UITabBarController. There are five view controllers in UITabBarController. I want to add a view that can be used in all these viewcontrollers or viewcontrollers that have the navigation bar.

The stupid way to do this is to add that view in every vc and of course I would not like this way. Is there any way that I can make use of UITabBarController or UINavigationController to make a view that can globally used?

The links Below is an example of other application. My app design is so similar with this app. You can see it has a navigation bar and a tab bar. The part I circled is what I would like to make! I would like to put this view under the navigation bar and above the child VC. A view that can be called and used globally without adding to every VC.

Thank you so much !!!!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oFgQ.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuuYy.jpg

Comment: add inside the window with the required frame instead of Navigation bar.

Comment: You can add one to the navigation controller.

Comment: sorry guys can you explain more?